# Working with group of checkboxes in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, form

I have the following checkbox as depicted by the image below:

[image: Screenshot]

The checkboxes are in 3 groups. Confidentiality, Integrity ad Availability. When the first in is clicked, the Confidentiality turns Red for High, Orange for Medium and Green for Low.

This is a lot of work to be done as you need to create a subroutine for each checkbox control. Below is a sample code for 2 checkboxes in the first line in the image above.

```
Private Sub CheckBox21_Change()

With Me.CheckBox21
If .Value Then ClearGroup .GroupName, .Name
End With

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox22_Change()

With Me.CheckBox22
If .Value Then ClearGroup .GroupName, .Name
End With

End Sub

Private Sub ClearGroup(sGroup As String, sName As String)
    Dim ole As OLEObject

        For Each ole In Me.OLEObjects
            If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
                If ole.Object.GroupName = sGroup And ole.Name <> sName Then
                    ole.Object.Value = False
                End If
            End If
        Next ole
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox21_Click()
    If CheckBox21.Value = True Then
    Range("i6", "m6").Value = "High"
    Range("r3").Value = "H"
    Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 0, 0)
    Range("r3").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 0, 0)

    Else
    CheckBox21.Value = False
    Range("i6", "m6").Value = "Low"
    Range("r3").Value = "L"
    Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
    Range("r3").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox22_Click()
    If CheckBox22.Value = True Then
    Range("i6", "m6").Value = "Medium"
    Range("r3").Value = "M"
    Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)
    Range("r3").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0)

    Else
    CheckBox22.Value = False
    Range("i6", "m6").Value = "Low"
    Range("r3").Value = "L"
    Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
    Range("r3").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any other way I can write the VBA code such that the overall line of code will be reduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's address your question first, then we'll talk about some other things that can be improved.

> This is a lot of work to be done as you need to create a subroutine for each checkbox control.

Well, yes and no. You **do** need to create an event routine for each control, but there's no reason to repeat all of that code over and over inside each of them. Extract the logic into a paramaterized method. Then, your event procedures will look something like this.

```
Private Sub CheckBox21_Click()
    HandleCheckBoxClick() 'we'll get to the parameters later
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox22_Click()
    HandleCheckBoxClick()
End Sub
```

Which isn't really so much work, is it?

However, to make this work cleanly, we'll need to define a simple data structre and populate it with appropriate values for high, medium, and low. I've used a `Type` here, but it might be worth creating a full blown class for down the road.

```
Private Type TStatus
    Name As String
    Abbreviation As String
    Color As Long
End Type
```

You'll want to store your three different statuses at the module level and create them at an appropriate time. Perhaps on the sheet activate event. Otherwise, you'll need to create them on the fly each time the procedure is run. I'm not sure which way I'd go, but the important part is abstracting the data right now.

```
Private high As TStatus
Private medium As TStatus
Private low As TStatus

Private Sub InitStatusVariables()
    high.Name = "High"
    high.Abbreviation = "H"
    high.Color = RGB(217, 0, 0) 'Red

    medium.Name = "Medium"
    medium.Abbreviation = "M"
    medium.Color = RGB(255, 204, 0) 'Orange

    low.Name = "Low"
    low.Abbreviation = "L"
    low.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0) ' Green
End Sub
```

So now, we can go ahead and write that `HandleCheckBoxClick` method. We'll pass in the actual checkbox control along with our predefined true state and false state.

```
Private Sub HandleCheckBoxClick(cntrl As CheckBox, trueState As TStatus, falseState As TStatus)
    If cntrl.Value = True Then
        Range("i6", "m6").Value = trueState.Name
        Range("r3").Value = trueState.Abbreviation
        Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = trueState.Color
        Range("r3").Interior.Color = trueState.Color

    Else
        cntrl.Value = False
        Range("i6", "m6").Value = falseState.Name
        Range("r3").Value = falseState
        Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = falseState.Color
        Range("r3").Interior.Color = falseState.Color
    End If
End Sub
```

Awesome, but now the duplication *inside* of the method has become really obvious, but thankfully, easier to deal with. So let's refactor again.

```
Private Sub HandleCheckBoxClick(cntrl As CheckBox, trueState As TStatus, falseState As TStatus)

    Dim state As TStatus
    If cntrl.Value = True Then
        state = trueState
    Else
        cntrl.Value = False
        state = falseState
    End If

    Range("i6", "m6").Value = state.Name
    Range("r3").Value = state.Abbreviation
    Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = state.Color
    Range("r3").Interior.Color = state.Color

End Sub
```

Note that in your full code, you will likely need to also pass the appropriate ranges into this method as well. Also, I'm not sure if you need this line of code, so I've left it's equivalent in the above method.

> ```
> Else
> CheckBox22.Value = False
> ```

Why set the value of the checkbox to `False` if it's not `True`? Shouldn't it already be false? Or can the value of a checkbox be "null"? I can't remember, but it's probably worth a comment if you're doing this to make sure the value is false instead of `Empty`.

---

This feels like an abuse of the `With` statement to me.

```
With Me.CheckBox21
If .Value Then ClearGroup .GroupName, .Name
End With
```

Why the `With` statement here? I don't see a real need for it. Maybe it's personal preference, but I think this version of it is nicer.

```
If Me.CheckBox21.Value = True Then 
    ClearGroup Me.Checkbox21.GroupName, Me.CheckBox21.Name
End If
```

Even better, instead of passing strings to the `ClearGroup` method, pass the whole CheckBox control.

```
 If Me.CheckBox21.Value = True Then ClearGroup Me.CheckBox21
```

There ya go. One line, nice and neat. It would also remove the need to check the type of the control within the method, because you already know it's a checkbox. It has to be, or you get a type mismatch error.

---

Your indentation is inconsistent. You do very well in some places, but very poorly in others.

**Good!**

> ```
>     For Each ole In Me.OLEObjects
>         If TypeName(ole.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
>             If ole.Object.GroupName = sGroup And ole.Name <> sName Then
>                 ole.Object.Value = False
>             End If
>         End If
>     Next ole
> ```

**Bad!**

> ```
> Private Sub CheckBox21_Click()
>     If CheckBox21.Value = True Then
>     Range("i6", "m6").Value = "High"
>     Range("r3").Value = "H"
>     Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 0, 0)
>     Range("r3").Interior.Color = RGB(217, 0, 0)
>
>     Else
>     CheckBox21.Value = False
>     Range("i6", "m6").Value = "Low"
>     Range("r3").Value = "L"
>     Range("i6", "m6").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
>     Range("r3").Interior.Color = RGB(153, 204, 0)
>     End If
>
> End Sub
> ```

Everything inside of an `If` block should be indented one level.

---

This is a bit harsh, but I'm not sure how else to put it... Your control names ***suck***. CheckBox21, CheckBox22, CheckBox23... It goes on and on and on doesn't it?

Take the time to give these meaningful names. Yes, it's going to take a while to name all of those checkboxes, but you'll thank yourself later, trust me.

---

Nifty little program you have there. I think you'll do well if you read up a bit about "Abstract Data Structures" and "Abstraction". All in all you write pretty neat and readable code. Those are good things.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @rubberDuck! This is actually my first time coding in VBA. Your criticisms were nice and instructive. I would love to work with you on this to finish the application. I'll apply all your inputs to have a more cleaner and less cumbersome code. I've got other questions though, would ask after implementing this one.

Comment: I'm around, so are several others. That's what we call [an iterative review](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c). So, please be sure to ask a new question. Note that if you have questions, but your code isn't quite ready for review, we do have a [VBA chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba) too.

Comment: Hmm I think refactor/rename isn't going to pick up worksheet controls. Very nice answer!

Comment: Hi @RubberDuck, you might be interested in this post 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793076/how-to-get-the-input-range-and-cell-link-of-an-excel-sheet. 

Would be waiting to read from you.